# How can I create an admin user on my live heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I tried going into the heroku console and adding a user with User.create(name: "admin", email: "admin@tradespring.net", admin: true). These are all valid columns in my user table and I have no problems creating an admin user locally (thought I do it differently. This is what it gives me.

```
irb(main):001:0> User.create(name: "admin", email:"admin@tradespring.net", admin: true)
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin
   (57.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (12.4ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('admin@tradespring.net') LIMIT 1
   (30.3ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<User id: nil, name: "admin", email: "admin@tradespring.net", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, remember_token: nil, admin: false>
```

clearly the admin setting didnt work as it is put as false. Also when I go to my site there is no new user named admin. I am not sure I am even taking the right steps though. What am I doing wrong/not doing?

Answer (score 1):

`User.create({name: "admin", email:"admin@tradespring.net", admin: true}, :without_protection => true)`

An alternative would be to set the attributes one by one:

```
u = User.new
u.name = "admin"
u.email = "admin@tradespring.net"
u.admin = true
u.save!
```

Comment: On a side note: A more important lesson to draw is why there's this mass assignment protection in the first place: http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment. This is especially so because you don't want anybody to abuse your `admin` attribute.